# Unnesting sf dataframe with list-column containing lubridate intervals

Tags: r, lubridate, r-sf

I start with an sf dataframe, called `polygon_history`, with the following columns:

```
polygon_id,valid_period,geometry
```

where `valid_period` is an interval between two dates created using lubridate package.

I subdivided `valid_period` into smaller intervals and combine them in a list by obtaining the intersection of the `valid_period` with a list of date ranges (`sectionized_periods`) that I am interested in analyzing separately, with the code below:

```
sectionized_periods
[1] 2021-09-01 UTC--2021-09-07 UTC 2021-09-07 UTC--2021-10-10 UTC 2021-10-10 UTC--2021-10-24 UTC 2021-10-24 UTC--2021-11-30 UTC

polygon_history %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(period_section = list(c(lubridate::intersect(valid_period,sectionized_periods))))
```

Now my table has the following columns:

```
polygon_id, valid_period, period_sections, geometry
```

where `period_sections` is a list-column; and every row is a list of [lubridate] intervals.

Example row in `period_sections`:

```
polygon_history$period_section[1]
[[1]]
[1] 2021-09-01 UTC--2021-09-07 UTC 2021-09-07 UTC--2021-10-10 UTC 2021-10-10 UTC--2021-10-24 UTC 2021-10-24 UTC--2021-11-30 UTC
```

I am trying to unnest this table based on the `period_section` list-column in order to have a row for each element of the list (each interval), however when I run the code below, I only get numeric values in `period_section` instead of the intervals. I believe this numeric value represents the duration of the interval, but I need to have the interval instead.

```
polygon_history <- polygon_history %>%
+     rowwise %>%
+     mutate(PERIOD_SECTION = list(c(lubridate::intersect(VALID_PERIOD,sectionized_periods)))) %>%
+     unnest(PERIOD_SECTION) %>%
+     sf::st_sf() 

polygon_history$PERIOD_SECTION
An object of class "vctrs:::common_class_fallback"
 [1]  518400 2851200 1209600 3196800  518400 2851200 1209600 3196800  518400 2851200 1209600 3196800  518400 2851200 1209600 3196800  518400 2851200
[19] 1209600
```

Appreciate any insights on how to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I needed using `unchop`.

```
 polygon_history <- polygon_history %>%
    +     rowwise %>%
    +     mutate(PERIOD_SECTION = list(c(lubridate::intersect(VALID_PERIOD,sectionized_periods)))) %>%
    +     unchop(PERIOD_SECTION) %>%
    +     sf::st_sf()
```